# Rounding a 3D point relative to a plane

Tags: c++, rounding, plane

I have a Plane class that holds *n* for normal and *q* for a point on the plane. I also have another point *p* that also lies on that plane. How do I go about rounding *p* to the nearest unit on that plane. Like snapping a cursor to a 3D grid but the grid can be rotating plane.

Image to explain: [image]

Red is the current point. Green is the rounded point that I'm trying to get.

Comment: I guess you can negate the plane normal to the whole thing so you will have a 2D representation of what you need, you can snap the point X and Y to the nearest point using simple arithmetics and then apply the plane normal again.

Comment: Yeah but how do you apply/negate plane normals. Those are just words to me and Google isn't being friendly today.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to achieve this is by taking the plane to define a rotated and shifted coordinate system. This allows you to construct the matrices for transforming a point in global coordinates into plane coordinates and back. Once you have this, you can simply transform the point into plane coordinates, perform the rounding/projection in a trivial manner, and convert back to world coordinates.

Of course, the problem is underspecified the way you pose the question: the transformation you need has six degrees of freedom, your plane equation only yields three constraints. So you need to add some more information: the location of the origin within the plane, and the rotation of your grid around the plane normal.

Personally, I would start by deriving a plane description in parametric form:

```
xVec = alpha*direction1 + beta*direction2 + x0
```

Of course, such a description contains nine variables (three vectors), but you can normalize the two direction vectors, and you can constrain the two direction vectors to be orthogonal, which reduces the amount of freedoms back to six.

The two normalized direction vectors, together with the normalized normal, are the base vectors of the rotated coordinate system, so you can simply construct the rotation matrix by putting these three vectors together. To get the inverse rotation, simply transpose the resulting matrix. Add the translation / inverse translation on the appropriate side of the rotation, and you are done.

Comment: And how would I go about doing that? Theory is not my forte.

Comment: That would depend on how exactly you are manipulating those objects. Are you using some library? You didn't specify anything we can use to help you.

Comment: Well I'm using GSL for matrices and vectors but I dont know how to set up a rotation matrix.